# `\documentclass{scrartcl}` not working in org-mode and emacs

Tags: pdftex, miktex, emacs, org-mode

I am trying to use `org-mode` for generating my documents in pdf format using `MiKTeX` in Windows environment. When use the class `\documentclass{scrartcl}` in `TexMaker`, it is working properly. But in org-mode it is not working. I want have a `\subtitle{}` and author affiliation in my document. But I am getting only Title, Author and Date in my document. My LaTeX header in org-mode looks like this:

```
#+TITLE: A demo paper in LaTeX
#+SUBTITLE: cse131:: Course Title
#+AUTHOR: R. Sreekumar
```

And in my `.emacs` configuration file, I have added `koma-article` class. It looks like this.

```
(require 'ox-latex)

(add-to-list 'org-latex-classes
          '("koma-article"
             "\\documentclass{scrartcl}"
             ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")
             ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}")
             ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}")
             ("\\paragraph{%s}" . "\\paragraph*{%s}")
             ("\\subparagraph{%s}" . "\\subparagraph*{%s}")))
```

I don't know where I am doing the mistake. If any expert in `org-mode` and `LaTeX` can help, I will be grateful.

Also, I am not sure, where `MiKTeX` is storing external style files which are automatically downloaded in `TexMaker`.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to tex.stackexchange!

I added `#+LATEX_CLASS: koma-article` below the line `#+AUTHOR`, see this example:

```
#+TITLE: Titel
#+SUBTITLE: untertitel
#+AUTHOR: wer auch immer
#+LATEX_CLASS: koma-article
```

That helped, in a way, because the subtitle gets exported as:

```
\title{Titel\\\medskip
\large untertitel}
```

But I failed to find out how to get something like `\subtitle:{untertitel}`

---

### EDIT

Ha, I got it! We need two variables.

The orgmode file

```
# -*- org-latex-subtitle-separate: t; org-latex-subtitle-format: "\\subtitle{ %s }"; -*-


#+TITLE: Titel
#+SUBTITLE: cse131:: untertitel
#+AUTHOR: wer auch immer
#+LATEX_CLASS: koma-article

* Erster Abschnitt

Text
* Zweiter Abschnitt

noch mehr text
** Unterabschnitt

was auch immer
```

will be exported as

```
% Created 2019-07-20 Sa 09:02
% Intended LaTeX compiler: pdflatex
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel, booktabs, libertine, setspace, array}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\author{wer auch immer}
\date{\today}
\title{Titel}
\subtitle{ cse131:: untertitel }
\hypersetup{
 pdfauthor={wer auch immer},
 pdftitle={Titel},
 pdfkeywords={},
 pdfsubject={},
 pdfcreator={Emacs 26.2 (Org mode 9.2.4)}, 
 pdflang={Germanb}}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents


\section{Erster Abschnitt}
\label{sec:orgb9ac65c}

Text
\section{Zweiter Abschnitt}
\label{sec:org880cd2d}

noch mehr text
\subsection{Unterabschnitt}
\label{sec:org29209c7}

was auch immer
\end{document}
```

Ok, my definitions from .emacs are:

```
(add-to-list 'org-latex-classes 
        '("koma-article"
        "\\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}
        [NO-DEFAULT-PACKAGES]
        [PACKAGES]
            \\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\n
            \\usepackage{babel, booktabs, libertine, setspace, array}\n
            \\usepackage{hyperref}\n"
             ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")
             ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}")
             ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}")
             ("\\paragraph{%s}" . "\\paragraph*{%s}")
             ("\\subparagraph{%s}" . "\\subparagraph*{%s}"))
        )
```

-- just for completness.

Comment: Sorry, this is not working for me.  `\documentclass{scrartcl}` is working in **texmaker** but **emacs** tells it couldn't locate the class. I added the following in my `.emacs` file, `(setq org-latex-subtitle-separate t) 
(setq org-latex-subtitile-format "\\subtitle{%s}")`, still it is not showing the subtitle.

Comment: Can you provide emacs message? Check spelling, please: the variable is `org-latex-subtitle-format`, not »...subtitile«.

Comment: I did correct the spelling mistake. And the emacs message isperfect without any errors. It created pdf file but without subtitle.